# Descargar Archivos/Imagenes Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estuve intentado descargar archivos o imágenes, pero simplemente me sale esto

**Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**

Mi ruta

```
   Route::get('/download/{$file}' , 'DetailController@downloadFile');
```

Mi controlador

```
public function downloadFile($file){
      $pathtoFile = public_path().'images/'.$file;
      return response()->download($pathtoFile);
    }
```

Mi vista

```
<a href='/download/{{$file}}'>Download</a>
```

Dónde esta mi error o si es que hay otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Empieza por corregir la ruta: `Route::get('/download/{file}'.....`

Comment: Muchas gracias incluyendo ese despiste se tiene que agregar // antes del directorio...  $pathtoFile = public_path().'//images/'.$file;

Comment: Ya quedó solucionado?

Comment: Si... muchas gracias :) debo de eliminar la pregunta? o hacer algo mas? Soy un poco nuevo en los foros de stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás especificando mal el parámetro de entrada obligatorio en la ruta, no necesitas el signo `$` antes del nombre del parámetro `file`:

```
Route::get('/download/{file}' , 'DetailController@downloadFile');
```

Más información en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#required-parameters

Comment: Muchas Gracias, fue un gran despiste :(